# Getting "Name servers refused query (lame delegation?)" when doing DNS look up in a Google Sheets Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dns

I'm developing a Google Sheets add-on with Google Apps Script. But when I do a `fetch` to any URL at `https://reboapp.co.uk`, I'm getting a vague `'DNS Error'`:

When trying the DNS query directly, I'm getting a response of `'Name servers refused query (lame delegation?)'`.

I have tested the DNS look up from within the add-on app script with:

```js
function testDNS() {
  var requestUrl = 'https://dns.google.com/resolve?name=reboapp.co.uk';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestUrl);
  var responseText = response.getContentText();
  var comment = JSON.parse(responseText).Comment;
  Logger.log(comment);
}
```

This logs:

```
"Name servers refused query (lame delegation?) [217.160.83.244, 217.160.81.244, 217.160.82.244]."
```

If I try the same request locally, it works fine. I haven't had any other problems with the DNS for this domain.

I've looked into why a DNS server might refuse a query, but haven't found anything concrete. It seems it is at the discretion of the DNS server. Does anyone know why Google might be refusing the query here, but not when queried outside of the app script?

This started to happen at the same time as I verified the domain to Google Webmaster tools, and submitted the app script project for OAuth verification, if that could be related somehow. Unfortunately the extent of Google support (who I'd prefer to ask this to directly) seems to be 'post on StackOverflow', so here I am. Thank you!